# FreeBSD Apache 2.4 rewrite/proxy module errors

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, freebsd, mod-proxy, apache-2.4

Just set up a FreeBSD jail to run httpd in it and all works good except these two, rewrite/proxy modules.

These are error logs excerpts:

**mod_rewrite** error:

> [rewrite:crit] [pid 43447] (13)Permission denied: AH00666:
>   mod_rewrite: could not init rewrite_mapr_lock_acquire in child

**mod_proxy** error:

> [proxy:crit] [pid 43447] (13)Permission denied: AH02479: could not
>   init proxy_mutex in child

Not sure permissions of *what* are being denied as html in document root is being served just fine when these modules are disabled.

I tried googling but found nothing but rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue were permissions.

I set /etc/pw.conf umask to 007 from default 022 and that resulted in certain executables being unable to be reached from jails.

Once i changed containing directory permissions to original ones it all started working properly and modules are not logging errors any more.

Typical example of **PEBKAC**.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your jail lacks permissions for SysV IPC. Try to set `sysvipc_allow=1` in your jail settings or pass it with `jail` command.

Comment: how does that harm isolation i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @purpler The handbook covers that: http://www.freebsd.no/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/jail-restrictions.html

Comment: "By default, this sysctl is set to 0. If it were set to 1, it would defeat the whole purpose of having a jail". So that's out of question. Why would mod_rewrite and mod_proxy need IPC?

Comment: If I've understood right, FreeBSD 9.x and later do allow setting sysvipc_allow and plethora of other restrictions on per-jail basis instead of global sysctl values.

Comment: I don't think we could call this a restriction, rather permission which renders the point of having jails completely useless.

Comment: I did try but I'm still seeing those error logs. Apache 2.2 works just fine completely jailed.